# Checking integers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a code that asks the user for a range of integers and then calculates which integers in that range have at least 3 factors (excluding 1 and the integer itself). I don't know how to take into consideration the fact that an integer can have multiple same factors, for example, in my code integer 8 returns a false value because the program divides it into two integers, 2 and 4. I want the return value to be true, because 8 can be divided into three factors of 2. How do i fix it?

```
def does_integer_have_3_or_more_factors(x):
    num_of_factors = 0
    for i in range(2, x):
        if x % i == 0:
            num_of_factors += 1
    if num_of_factors >= 3 :
        return True
    else :
        return False

def main():
    integer1 = int(input("Give first positive integer.\n"))
    integer2 = int(input("Give last integer.\n"))
    print("These integers have at least 3 factors.")
    for x in range(integer1, integer2 + 1):
        if does_integer_have_3_or_more_factors(x) == True:
            print(x)


main()
```

Comment: Factors cannot repeat. The factors of 8 are 1,2,4,8

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question ... 8 should return False because it has factors: 1, 2, 4 and 8 where your definition asks for 3 or more factors excluding 1 and 8. If you want to include 1 and the number yourself, you only need one more factor, otherwise I think your solution does what you stated you wanted it to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the factors you found, and apply them as often as necessary. Maybe you also want to keep track of the factors you found.

```
factors = []
...
for ... # see below
    while x > 1 and not x%i:
        factors.append(i)
        x /= i
```

You can also stop checking for factors after `sqrt(x)` has been reached.

```
from math import sqrt
for i in range(2,int(sqrt(x))+1):
```

Finally, you're handling booleans in an overly complicated way. Just do

```
return len(factors) > 2  # "len(factors) > 2" will result in True or False directly
```

and check for

```
if does_integer_have_3_or_more_factors(x):
    print(x)
```